# centre multirow horizontally

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multirow

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|r|l|}
    \multirow{2}{*}{Sample} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{AA}\\
                            & B            & B \\
    sssssssssssssss1        & 111111111    & 22222222222222222222\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

How to centre the `multirow` horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine column type locally as usual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|r|l|}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Sample}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{AA}\\
                            & B            & B \\
    sssssssssssssss1        & 111111111    & 22222222222222222222\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since you load `makecell`, use `\multirowcell` – in addition, the syntax doesn't require the width argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{|l|r|l|}
    \multirowcell{2}{Sample} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{AA}\\
                            & B & B \\
    sssssssssssssss1 & 111111111 & 22222222222222222222\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{|l|r|l|}
    \Block[c]{2-1}{Sample} & \Block{1-2}{AA} \\
                        & B               & B \\
    sssssssssssssss1    & 111111111       & 22222222222222222222\\
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]